# Tie a Java class instance to a C++ class instance

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to write a wrapper for a dynamic library that I do not have all of the source code for, just as most people who use JNI seem to be trying to do.

What I need to do is call the constructor of a C++ class with a Java wrapper class and then use that C++ class instance for all further native methods through the Java class's instance. This works fine as long as there is only ever one instance of the Java class, as soon as a new instance is made the old C++ instance is overwritten with a new one. I must be able to create multiple instances as each instance handles a single sensor.

Is there any way to elegantly tie the Java class instance to the C++ class instance?

Disclaimer:I am not a C++ programmer any more than a monkey is a human. Even the simplest answers on the C++ end might help.

Comment: This might be one of those rare valid use cases for a Singleton?

Comment: @Yuushi: I'm not sure the OP actually *wants* a single instance.

Comment: @Cantos You are right, I have updated the OP to explain that I need to make more than one instance.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but you may want to check out [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/). Let me know if you have a more specific use case and I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get yourself familiar to the concept of *peer classes*.

That is thoroughly described in this online book from Sun (or Oracle to be picky): [Peer Classes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/stubs.html#30234).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me, I should have read that chapter more thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the java class Singleton and ensure that no other instance of java class is being created. 
I guess this is the solution You can do for this

Comment: Problem with this solution is that i need to make separate instances of the class, each to handle a separate sensor.

Comment: Better implement an interface that handle separate instances.

Answer (score 0):

Being completely unaware of peer classes, i would do the following: Have a `native void register()` (or such) in your Java class which you want to pair. In C JNI part, store a `GlobalRef` of the calling `jobject` as a key in `std::map<jobject,NativeImplementationObject>`. You can set the `GlobalRef` key to the C++ object via constructor, to simplify callbacks to JVM. On any subsequent call from JVM to any sensor-related native methods, look up the right `NativeImplementationObject` by doing `IsSameObject` comparison with the current calling jobject. Then simply "forward" the call to that object. The JNI stub implementation will be just a thin dispatcher holding the map. There is of course nontrivial part of deleting all objects and global refs at appropriate time (no automagic JVM) but that's beyond what can be explained here.

On a second thought, you may not need a map, unless the number of sensors will be moderately big (on the order of tens at least) or you are willing to learn some human skills by writing compare predicate function using the mentioned `IsSameObject`. A simple list of structs would do as well (for monkeys and humans alike).